# Face morphing using GAN

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, gan

I need to morph multiple faces.

Here is the desired result:
[image]
I already tried to find facial landmarks using [dlib](https://github.com/davisking/dlib/) shape predictor and then morph multiple faces, but unfortunately sometimes shape predictor gives wrong results.

So now I think I can use some type of Generative adversarial network(GAN) for this task.
As I understand they can do something similar to my task, e.g. [CycleGAN](https://junyanz.github.io/CycleGAN/). 
Also, I already saw [article](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1703.10717.pdf) which has similar intermediate result (you can see it in the figure 4, but it's not exactly what I need). 
Finally, a couple of years ago I heard about type of GAN which exactly do multiple faces morphing, but I can't find it now unfortunately.

So, can you advice GAN which exactly do multiple faces morphing? Or can you advice appropriate type of GAN and how can I change it for multiple faces morphing?

Comment: Any luck with this?

Comment: @colt.exe nope, unfortunately.